# Get available stocks to sell

Tags: mysql

What I have until now: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfec/6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfec/3)

I want to get the quanity of shares for a given stock, that a given company has available to sell - grouped by price. For example, for company number 9 and stock number 1, I want the data like this:

```
 | id | name | price |           date        | quantity |  total  |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 3  | ALTR | 2.240 |  2015-05-12 04:29:29  |    50    |  112.00 |
 | 7  | ALTR | 2.449 |  2014-06-10 18:21:02  |    50    |  122.45 |
```

Because company 9 bought 200 stocks on 2015-05-12 04:29:29, sold 100 on 2014-06-10 15:50:17, more 50 on 2014-06-10 17:06:18 and bought 50 on 2014-06-10 18:21:02.

I don't want the total of all shares, because they have different prices when a company acquires them. The price and the date are the purchasing price and date but the quantity is what is left from a certain purchasing.

Thanks in advance.

Strawberry, the desired result:

```
 | id | price |     date     | quantity |
 -----------------------------------------------
 | 3  | 2.240 |  12-05-2015  |    50    |
 | 7  | 2.449 |  10-06-2014  |    50    |
```

Comment: Also, as you mention above, some of the dates are 2015, but is that correct?

Comment: Yup. I have a virtual calendar so the time has a direct match between now and what admin defined.

Comment: Ricardo, I think you may need to provide a more properly representative data set (and amended result set). This one is too limited to be useful. Ignore the other tables for now. Just focus on the transactions table.

Comment: What, with more transactions? I want a group by id_empresa, so we can forget other records. We can forget about total too, for now. This is a better fiddle, I think: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05c06/4. In that link is what I want but without remaining shares. I want to add another row with the remaining shares.

Comment: So what would that look like. Answer above. Also, note that money is normally stored as DECIMAL.

Comment: I don't know how to answer above... I will answer it in my post.

Comment: That's what I meant! :-)

Comment: Ok, I think I got it... Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69112/5. Do you think that's correct? Because, if I sell something I always want to get minimum, right?

Comment: Forget my last comment... Not working...

Comment: Now I think I got it... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfec/51

Comment: Looks good. Note that COALESCE() conforms to the SQL standard... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfec/62 - although I don't really understand what difference it makes which packet you sell from. Overall, your profits are going to be the same!?! But hey, what do I know!

Comment: Thank you :) I will update that, as decimal to money fields. Yes, if you look at the profit it will be the same, but I want this to give the user the possibility to choose from which shares he wants to sell. Maybe you're right... I'll think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I think I got it.
Here's the query resulting what I wanted:

```
SELECT p.id
   , a.nome
   , p.preco
   , date_format(p.`data`,'%m/%d/%Y') AS `data`
   , COALESCE(p.quantidade-SUM(f.quantidade), p.quantidade) AS quantidade
   , p.preco*COALESCE(p.quantidade-SUM(f.quantidade), p.quantidade) AS total 
   FROM acao_trans p 
   LEFT JOIN acao_trans f 
   ON p.id=f.parent 
   INNER JOIN acao a 
   ON p.id_acao=a.id 
   WHERE p.parent IS NULL 
   AND p.id_acao=1 
   AND p.id_empresa=9 
   GROUP BY p.id
```

Fiddle: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfec/64](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfec/51).

What I did: I joined the table that matters (acao_trans "p") with itself ("f") and I used Sum function to aggregate all the quantities of second argument, giving me the total of all sold shares. If there are records on "f" I want to subtract that total of the quantity of purchasing shares ("p"). If there is not a correspondence it will show null fields and I show purchased quantity. After it's done it's kind of simple. Quantity was what really mattered here, with that I was able to reach other things easily.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
select id_acao, id_empresa, ifnull(bought,0) - ifnull(sold,0) as stock
from
(
select id_acao, id_empresa, 
(select sum(quantidade) from acao_trans where tipo='C' and id_acao=a.id_acao and id_empresa=a.id_empresa) as bought,
(select sum(quantidade) from acao_trans where tipo='V' and id_acao=a.id_acao and id_empresa=a.id_empresa) as sold 
from acao_trans a group by id_acao,id_empresa
) x
;
+---------+------------+-------+
| id_acao | id_empresa | stock |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       1 |          4 |  1500 |
|       1 |          9 |   100 |
|       8 |          9 |  3500 |
|      13 |          9 |  5000 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

And join this query to your base acao and empresa tables.

Remark: For statistics etc. it would be easier to use negative quantities for selling transactions instead of a transaction type 'C' and 'V'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I don't want the total of all shares, because they have different prices when a company acquires them. I want a result like I've shown in my post. The price and the date are the purchasing price and date but the quantity is what is left from a certain purchasing.

Comment: You want to group by id_acao, id_empresa and each buy transaction with all subsequent sell transactions up to but excluding the next buy - right?

Comment: No. I want to group by id_acao all remaining shares. So if I buy 50 shares of ALTR I want to see those 50 shares, but I also want to see remaining shares if there are any. In the example are 50 remaining shares for ALTR of id_empresa nº 9.

Comment: So if in your example the empresa sold 30 shares of ALTR on 2014-06-11, what would your result show - do you substract it from the first batch of bought stock or from the second? How do you know from which purchase you subtract your sale if there are more than one?

Comment: I subtract it from what they choose to sell. The field "parent" (Fiddle example) tells me from which shares user sold. In the example that I gave if you choose to sell 30 shares of ALTR on 2014-06-11 you have to choose from which shares would you like to sell and parent will be 3 or 7 depending on your choose. The result would be the same as the example with 20 shares in the row that you choose (3 or 7).

Comment: I understand now, but does it make any sense to differentiate between the purchase batches against which you book your sales? I mean, if you buy 50 and 100 and then sell 20 and 80, you keep 50, no matter at which price you bought or sold them.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but in this case it makes sense because administrators want to know how much you win in a sell. And to give you the change to maximize your profit. Imagine this: you buy 50 shares of ALTR today and tomorrow another 50. It can happen that you can get profit if you sell first 50 and not if you sell from second 50. So, I think it makes sense like this...

Answer (score 0):

For ease of (my) comprehension, I translated and adjusted your stock table slightly...

```
SELECT a.stock_id
     , a.company_id
     , a.transaction_date
     , a.price
     , COALESCE(a.quantity - SUM(b.quantity),a.quantity) quantity 
     , COALESCE(a.quantity - SUM(b.quantity),a.quantity) * a.price subtotal
  FROM stock_company a  
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.stock_id
     , x.company_id
     , MAX(x.transaction_date) min_transaction_date
     , y.quantity 
  FROM stock_company x 
  JOIN stock_company y 
    ON y.stock_id = x.stock_id 
   AND y.company_id = x.company_id 
   AND y.transaction_date <= x.transaction_date 
   AND y.transaction_type <> x.transaction_type
 WHERE y.transaction_type = 'SELL' 
 GROUP 
    BY x.stock_id
     , x.company_id
     , y.quantity
     ) b 
    ON b.stock_id = a.stock_id 
   AND b.company_id = a.company_id 
   AND b.min_transaction_date = a.transaction_date 
 WHERE a.stock_id = 1 
   AND a.company_id = 9
   AND a.transaction_type = 'BUY'
 GROUP 
    BY stock_id
     , company_id
     , transaction_date;

+----------+------------+---------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| stock_id | company_id | transaction_date    | price | quantity | subtotal |
+----------+------------+---------------------+-------+----------+----------+
|        1 |          9 | 2014-06-10 18:21:02 | 2.449 |       50 |  122.450 |
|        1 |          9 | 2015-05-12 04:29:29 | 2.240 |       50 |  112.000 |
+----------+------------+---------------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfa4d/1

Note that this hasn't been tested extensively so there may be a flaw (or perhaps several flaws!) in my logic, but it seems to work well enough on the data set provided.

EDIT: I made a slight adjustment - still not sure if it's enough. Let me know.

Comment: I just noticed the "parent" field - maybe we better use that one for joining?

Comment: Yes, I have to use parent, otherwise I can't know from which buy a user sell.

Comment: See edit. Are you sure that parent is necessary for this particular query?

Comment: The parent still does not make sense to me. If I buy 50 XYZ (id = 1) and then again 50 (id = 2) and then sell 30 (parent = 1) and then sell 70 - which parent does the last transaction have?

Comment: Strawberry, it's still not this :/ yes, parent is necessary, I think. Because without that I can't know the remaining shares of a certain purchasing.

Comment: Alex Monthy, you can't sell 70 at a time in that case. If you want to sell 70 you have to do 2 sell operations. 20 of the remaining (id=1) and 50 (id=2).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe now I've understood it. How about this:

```
select c.id,c.id_empresa,c.id_acao,c.data as c_data,c.quantidade as c_quantidade,v.preco,v.id as v_id,v.data as v_data,ifnull(v.quantidade,0) as v_quantidade, c.preco*v.quantidade as bought, v.preco*v.quantidade as sold
from acao_trans c 
left join acao_trans v 
on c.id=v.parent
order by id_empresa, id_acao,c_data,v_data
```

which results in

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+--------------+-------+------+---------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
| id | id_empresa | id_acao | c_data              | c_quantidade | preco | v_id | v_data              | v_quantidade | bought   | sold     |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+--------------+-------+------+---------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|  4 |          4 |       1 | 2014-06-10 08:59:09 |         2000 | 2.385 |    8 | 2014-06-11 10:39:48 |          500 | 1184.000 | 1192.500 |
|  8 |          4 |       1 | 2014-06-11 10:39:48 |          500 |  NULL | NULL | NULL                |            0 |     NULL |     NULL |
|  5 |          9 |       1 | 2014-06-10 15:50:17 |          100 |  NULL | NULL | NULL                |            0 |     NULL |     NULL |
|  6 |          9 |       1 | 2014-06-10 17:06:18 |           50 |  NULL | NULL | NULL                |            0 |     NULL |     NULL |
|  7 |          9 |       1 | 2014-06-10 18:21:02 |           50 |  NULL | NULL | NULL                |            0 |     NULL |     NULL |
|  3 |          9 |       1 | 2015-05-12 04:29:29 |          200 | 2.430 |    5 | 2014-06-10 15:50:17 |          100 |  224.000 |  243.000 |
|  3 |          9 |       1 | 2015-05-12 04:29:29 |          200 | 2.449 |    6 | 2014-06-10 17:06:18 |           50 |  112.000 |  122.450 |
|  2 |          9 |       8 | 2015-05-12 04:27:56 |         3500 |  NULL | NULL | NULL                |            0 |     NULL |     NULL |
|  1 |          9 |      13 | 2015-05-12 04:25:52 |         5000 |  NULL | NULL | NULL                |            0 |     NULL |     NULL |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+--------------+-------+------+---------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Can you go on from there?

Comment: I tried but I don't think I can... I'll try harder.

Comment: Alex, I think multiple answers from the same individual is going to get confusing.